# Sql Returning null from second select

Tags: sql, select, null

I have a query like this

```
select * from Cars where 
car_id!=(Select car_id from reservation where reservation_date between '2013-05-13' and '2013-05-15')
```

I want to take car_id='' if nothing between that dates but it's not working.

Comment: What SQL engine are you speaking about? Try `NVL( subquery, '' )`

Answer (score 2):

First check if this is returning proper values

```
Select car_id 
   from reservation 
   where reservation_date 
   between '2013-05-13' and '2013-05-15'
```

Try this:

```
select * 
from Cars 
where car_id
not in 
(
   Select car_id 
     from reservation 
     where reservation_date between '2013-05-13' and '2013-05-15'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using "not in" as per draxxxeus's answer will work, but once you get large amounts of data, your query will be slow.  A less intuitive, but logically equivalent way of getting the answer is like this:

```
where car_id in 
(select car_id
from cars
except 
select car_id
from reservation
etc
)
```

If your database supports that syntax, it will run faster than using "not in".  With some databases, Oracle for example, you have to use the word "minus" instead of "except".

Comment: . . The performance of `not in` is database dependent.  Even on databases where it generally performs poorly, it is usually quite efficient with the right indexes.